# use the selenium library in the part of the webdriver common keys in a .EXE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I've been trying to make an .EXE in pyinstaller  with the selenium library, but it already makes me the executable and everything but it does not load all the selenium library since in the part where the webdriver.common.keys should work, it does not execute anything

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os, sys, inspect 
current_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))

def init_driver():
    chromedriver = os.path.join(current_folder,"chromedriver-Windows")
    # via this way, you explicitly let Chrome know where to find 
    # the webdriver.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver)
    return driver

driver = init_driver()

driver.get("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada")
driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput").send_keys("tuna")
driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

the output of the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taylor19\Desktop\robot\soi\prueba_soi1.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput").send_keys("tuna")
  File "C:\pyton\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\pyton\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\pyton\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\pyton\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: First thing to do is to update your version of `chromedriver` because it's mismatched.  See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: all ready do that but still the problem